# rails ujs call on subset of class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks, rails-ujs

Class `Usercontent` has records being generated and shown via AJAX calls with turbolinks, essentially the rails way, aside from jQuery3 being invoked in a rails 5 app.

However there are two rendering cases, one for all objects of the class (`usercontent`), another for a subset (`point`), on the same page, but in tabs, with two distinct forms and the following `usercontents.js` javascript.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('[data-js-usercontent-form]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var usercontent = $(xhr.responseText).hide();
    $('#usercontents').append(usercontent);
    usercontent.fadeIn(1000);
  });

  $('[data-js-usercontent-id]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var usercontent_id = xhr.responseJSON.id;
    $('[data-js-usercontent-id=' + usercontent_id + ']').hide();
  });
  $('[data-js-point-form]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var point = $(xhr.responseText).hide();
    $('#points').append(point);
    point.fadeIn(1000);
  });    

  $('[data-js-point-id]').on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
    var point_id = xhr.responseJSON.id;
    $('[data-js-point-id=' + point_id + ']').hide();
  });
});
```

the controller declares the two collections

```
@usercontents = Usercontent.all
@points = Usercontent.where(['contenttype_id = ?', 1]).all
```

the view has two distinct calls to the collections

```
<div id=points class='tableize'>
  <%= render @points %>

<div id=usercontents class='tableize'>
  <%= render @usercontents %>
```

who in turn call the individual item to be updated via AJAX  `_point.html.erb` (both partials are in the views/usercontents directory)

```
<div class='row' data-js-point-id=<%= point.id %>>
```

and `_usercontent.html.erb`

```
<div class='row' data-js-usercontent-id=<%= usercontent.id %>>
```

The problem is the former renders the 'full' collection with the wrong `data-js` call :

```
<div id="points" class="tableize">
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="33"></div>
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="34"></div>
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="35"></div>
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="36"></div>
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="37"></div>
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="38"></div>
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="39"></div>
  <div class="row" data-js-usercontent-id="48"></div>
</div>
```

Clearly `render @points` is not rendering properly.  How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because:

> Rails determines the name of the partial to use by looking at the
>   model name in the collection.
>   ([source](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections))

which means your partial `_point.html.erb` is never used.

The `@points` collection is rendered within the `_usercontent.html.erb` because it contains `Usercontent` records.

To fix your issue, render the partial by pointing the right context:

```rb
<div id=points class='tableize'>
  <%= render partial: "point", collection: @points %>
```

---

Comment: I had the inkling of this, but sometimes rails  magic is hard to fathom.  It can be easily assumed that rails will take the singular of the declared collection...  In your response, there is an issue that is still unclear to me.  This essentially says redner @ points collection with partial point.  However that partial should be a series of rows  and `<div class='row' data-js-point-id=<%= point.id %>>` then has a problem in being properly identified (`point`is effectively unidentified)

Comment: yes, the partial is now invoked, but `undefined local variable or method `point' for #<#<Class:`  on the partial when trying to call the member `<div class='row' data-js-point-id=<%= point.id %>>`.  Same error with `<%= render "point", collection: @points, as: :point  %>`

Comment: @Jerome yes it's my mistake, you need to add the key `:partial`. I updated my answer.

Comment: and rather unbrilliantly, I missed that in the guide when it was staring at me...

Comment: however... that ends up being tautological.  Calling `render` by definition calls a partial... that's a gotcha...